# Xcode framework - not have to annotate everywhere with #available

Tags: ios13

In Xcode I wanted to create a 'framework A' for SwiftUI Code that is supported only in iOS13 but still have my deployment target for the application as iOS11 without having to annotate everywhere in 'framework A' with #available..

In my application, i want to check for the presence of iOS13 on that device and then branch into code that uses 'framework A' only otherwise fallback to what I already have as existing functionality.

How can I do this? anybody done this before for any previous iOS versions?